# Running AC solenoid vibration pump with DC voltage

Tags: ac, dc, solenoid, fluid-pump

Ulka e series solenoid vibration pump works with Ac voltage directly connected to main power.
They are rated at 220, 110, 24 voltage 50-60 Hz.
These pumps use an internal diode for removing half cycle of AC voltage.
The manufacturer specification does not determine the voltage as pure sine ac voltage.

Full specification of Ulka e series vibration pumps : http://ulka-ceme.co.uk/Ulka_E_Models.html

The question is that can these kind of pumps be running with square wave DC voltage controlled with pwm at 50-60 Hz without problem?
Will it damage the pump ? or reduce its lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you could use a DC square wave, but I would be careful about using PWM because they were designed to produce a specific amount of output at a rated power.
An insufficient (too short) duty cycle could make them either inoperational or less than properly operational.
A duty cycle of more than 50% or 10ms could overload and overheat the coil.
Some models have a maximum running time specified in minutes, followed by a specified minimum OFF time in minutes, so you have to be careful if using those (best not to get those models).